# Why is there a 0 second delay between two captured packets in my libpcap session?

Tags: c++, networking, logging, libpcap

My forking proxy duplicates for every incoming connection: every child process launches a detached thread which logs packets for that connection with a `pcap` session. Looking in my log file I found a 0 second delay between two captured packets belonging to the same connection.

I don't know if this is because of a mistake of mine, or there's something I'm missing in the `pcap` library but this is a serious isuue for me: delay is used to compute packets per second with the formula `1000000 / delay` (delay is in microseconds).

Is this something I should worry about? Or the `pcap_pkthdr` doesn't provide enough precision? I'm not familiar with how fast packets are received (proxy is running in my laptop and I'm using my modest home network, 5 Mbps in download).

This happens only with downloading packets (while I'm getting a Debian ISO or watching a YouTube video) and it occurs 10 times in almost 80000 captured packets. If the `timeval` in `pcap_pkthdr` would use `nanoseconds`, would the 0 delay disappear?

Anyway, here's the code every logging thread executes:

```
int res;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_t *handle;
struct bpf_program fp;
bpf_u_int32 net = PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN;
struct pcap_pkthdr *header;
const u_char *pkt_data;
struct timeval oldTimeUploadStruct;
struct timeval oldTimeDownloadStruct;

const char *filter_exp = // big filter of mine

handle = pcap_open_live("wlan0", 65535, 0, 1000, errbuf);
if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device wlan0: %s\n", errbuf);
    return;
}

// Compile and apply the filter
if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
    pcap_close(handle);
    return;
}
if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
    pcap_close(handle);
    return;
}

gettimeofday(&oldTimeUploadStruct, NULL);
gettimeofday(&oldTimeDownloadStruct, NULL);

long long oldTimeUpload = (oldTimeUploadStruct.tv_sec * 1000000) + oldTimeUploadStruct.tv_usec;
long long oldTimeDownload = (oldTimeDownloadStruct.tv_sec * 1000000) + oldTimeDownloadStruct.tv_usec;

// stopLogging is a flag set to false from child process before detaching this thread; 
// when connection is over, the flag is set to true and this loop breaks
while ((res = pcap_next_ex(handle, &header, &pkt_data)) && (stopLogging == false)) {

    // 0 if the timeout set with pcap_open_live() has elapsed.
    // In this case pkt_header and pkt_data don't point to a valid packet
    if (res == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    if (packet is in upload) {
        long long timestamp = (header->ts.tv_sec * 1000000) + header->ts.tv_usec;
        long long delay = timestamp - oldTimeUpload;
        std::stringstream mylogstream;
        // creating string to log: I omitted some variables
        // like IP addresses and ports for brevity
        mylogstream << host << " UPLOAD " << timestamp << ' ' << header->caplen << ' ' << delay;
        // logging captured packet
        std::string mylog = mylogstream.str();
        fs << mylog;
        oldTimeUpload = timestamp;
    }

    else if (packet is in download) {
        long long timestamp = (header->ts.tv_sec * 1000000) + header->ts.tv_usec;
        long long delay = timestamp - oldTimeDownload;
        std::stringstream mylogstream;
        mylogstream << host << " DOWNLOAD " << timestamp << ' ' << header->caplen << ' ' << delay;
        // logging captured packet
        std::string mylog = mylogstream.str();
        fs << mylog;
        oldTimeDownload = timestamp;
    }
}

if(res == -1)
    printf("Error reading the packets: %s\n", pcap_geterr(handle));

debugGreen("Quit logging connection towards " << hostName);
pcap_close(handle);
```

Comment: Have you inspected the packet contents?

Comment: Also, it might happen that a frame on pcap be splitted on several parts. (check header->caplen != header->len)

Comment: Two things. 1) you could average the delay over a few packets. 2) it could be that they arrive at the same time, due to packets aggregation

Comment: Adding to @Jonas, you could implement a kalman filter to average the delay

Comment: What about a `continue` statement if `delay == 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you got two packets within the same CPU clock tick. Since network cards raise interrupts when they receive packets this is possible.

Comment: Why did someone downvote my question? Was it too vague for this site?

Comment: Your sentence is opinable: did you reverse engineered the network card to find out I received two packets within the same CPU clock tick or did you use the knowledge you gained in the years to answer me?
I guess the second one. I don't have the knowledge to understand where to search, that's why I posted on this site.

Comment: I did not know until you asked the question it could happen. The knowledge required is found within your question.

Comment: Then, there was no need for research: my only fault was not to think of interrupts coming from my NIC, and this because of my lack of knowledge, not lack of research. I'm far from beeing similar to the ones who paste their code here asking just "why won't it work?", I don't think I deserve the upvote.